# How to prove this inequality without use of computers?

Tags: calculus, inequality, contest-math

With help from Maple, I got 
$$\left(\frac{ax+by+cz}{x-y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ay+bz+cx}{y-z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{az+bx+cy}{z-x}\right)^2-(c-a)^2-(c-b)^2$$
equal to
$$\frac{(c(x^3+y^3+z^3)+(a-c)(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)+(b-c)(x^2z+y^2x+z^2y)-3(a+b-c)xyz)^2}{(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(x-z)^2}$$ which of course is $\ge 0$.

But with no help from a computer algebra, how would one prove:$$\left(\frac{ax+by+cz}{x-y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ay+bz+cx}{y-z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{az+bx+cy}{z-x}\right)^2\ge (c-a)^2+(c-b)^2 ?$$

Comment: Just do the computation that Maple did by hand. Just mulpiply out.

Comment: Even if you expand out by hand, you won't recognize that the numerator is the square of this complicated expression.

Comment: If Maple did, you can too. Everything that Maple can do, a human can do. The thing is, Maple does it faster, that's all.

Comment: Perhaps <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead's_inequality#References"> Muirhead's inequality</a> can help.

Comment: I meant <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead's_inequality">Muirhead's inequality<a/>.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: "Everything that Maple can do, a human can do" may be true (even if the shortness of human lifespan makes it not very useful), but note that Maple isn't programmed to do only things obvious to all humans. To recognise that the numerator is a square, Maple may be using some non-trivial algorithms. (The algorithms by Gosper, Wilf-Zeilberger etc. as in [the book "A=B"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) come to mind.) So "do it by hand" is not a complete answer to this question; it still needs to be explained to a human *how* to recognise that the numerator is a square.

Answer (score 8):

This problem may be amenable to the "Purkiss Principle". I'll leave it as an exercise for you to determine if it can be applied here. But even if not you should read the following beautiful article on it by Wm. Waterhouse [Do Symmetric Problems Have Symmetric Solutions?](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=2941) I recall thinking that this was one of the most beautiful Monthly articles that I ever read as an undergraduate. Apparently others felt similarly since it won a prestigious Lester R. Ford award for expository excellence.

Comment: Thanks for the very nice reference! But of course it seems that the Purkiss symmetry principle is not very useful here: the expresssion is symmetric in $x, y, z$, but putting them equal gives zeroes in the denominator. (One could also say it's symmetric in $x-y$, $y-z$ and $z-x$, but that's saying the same thing.)

Answer (score 2):

We may express it in matrix form. Let $u = [a, \ b, \ c]^\mathsf{T}$,
$p_1 = [x, \ y, \ z]^\mathsf{T}$, $p_2 = [y, \ z, \ x]^\mathsf{T}$,
$p_3 = [z, \ x, \ y]^\mathsf{T}$,
$q_1 = [-1, \ 0, \ 1]^\mathsf{T}$ and $q_2 = [0, \ -1, \ 1]^\mathsf{T}$.
Let
$$S = \frac{1}{(x-y)^2} p_1p_1^\mathsf{T}
+ \frac{1}{(y-z)^2} p_2p_2^\mathsf{T} + \frac{1}{(z-x)^2} p_3p_3^\mathsf{T}
- q_1q_1^\mathsf{T} - q_2q_2^\mathsf{T}.$$
We have $\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} = u^\mathsf{T}S u$.

It suffices to prove that $S$ is positive semidefinite.

Note that all $2\times 2$ minors of $S$ are zero
(e.g., $S_{1,1} S_{2,2}-S_{1,2}S_{2,1} = 0$, etc.). Thus, $\mathrm{rank}(S)\le 1$.
Also, $S_{1,1} = x^2/(x-y)^2+y^2/(y-z)^2+z^2/(z-x)^2-1 > 0$
(the proof is not difficult).
Thus, $S$ is positive semidefinite. We are done.

Comment: Nice. It seems you have really mastered the general SOS method. When I was in high school and used to do   contest inequalities, the most exciting thing was uvw method and only few was aware of it.

Comment: @dezdichado I think that Holder and BW are two main tools for many tough inequalities. The technique of using Holder inequality to remove the root sign is impressive.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a solution, but a simplification. 
Claim: it is enough to consider the case $c,z=1$.
Proof(sketch only because long):
Denote $f(a,b,c,x,y,z):=\left(\frac{ax+by+cz}{x-y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ay+bz+cx}{y-z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{az+bx+cy}{z-x}\right)^2 - (c-a)^2-(c-b)^2$.
Then $f(a,b,c,x,y,z)=f(a,b,c,\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1)$. So we have to investigate two cases, case 1) $z=1$, case 2) $z=0$.

Case 1) $z=1$.
Define the function $f1(a,b,c,x,y):=\left(\frac{ax+by+c}{x-y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ay+b+cx}{y-1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a+bx+cy}{1-x}\right)^2 - (c-a)^2-(c-b)^2$.
Then $c^2 f1(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c},1,x,y)=f1(a,b,c,x,y)$ so we have two cases (i) $c=0$, (ii) $c=1$.

(i) $c=0$. Now we have two subcases, (a) $a=0$, (b) $a=1$.They are simply enough to handle by a human.

(ii) $c=1$. This is not so simple, but a human can handle this case also.

Case 2) $z=0$.We have two subcases, (i) $c=1$, (ii) $c=0$.
The last one is again handable by a human.

So we have the case $c,z=1$. It is more complicated, but more or less we can say a human is able to recognize the complete square expression.

**Edit:** a confusing misprint is corrected. (Originally there was Case 1) $z=0$ Define the $\ldots$.)

Comment: I don't understand why in Case 1) $z=0$, your $f1(a,b,c,x,y)\neq f(a,b,c,x,y,0)$?

Comment: @TCL This corrected version can answer your question?

Comment: I made one more correction.

Answer (score 1):

This solution should be considered reasonable. First observe that both sides of the inequality is quadratic in $c,$ and expanding to get explicit forms of those quadratics is not difficult. Namely, the RHS is:
$$R(c) = 2c^2 - 2c(a+b) + a^2+b^2.$$

The LHS is a bit more tedious so let's compute the coefficients separately. Write $LHS:=L(c) = Ac^2+2Bc+Cc$ and then:
$$\begin{cases}
A = \dfrac{x^2}{(y-z)^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{(z-x)^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{(x-y)^2}\\
2B = 2\sum\limits_{cyc}\dfrac{z}{(x-y)^2}(ax+by)\\
C = \sum{cyc}\dfrac{(ax+by)^2}{(x-y)^2}
\end{cases}.$$

First, we tackle $A.$ Actually, it is sort of a well-known identity/inequality as:
$$A - 2=\left(\dfrac{x}{y-z}+\dfrac{y}{z-x}+\dfrac{z}{x-y}\right)^2\geq 0,\quad (1).$$
I leave the solution to the above as a simple exercise. The more interesting one is $C,$ which basically was solved as a separate problem [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419508/let-x-y-z-in-bbb-r-prove-that-big-frac2x-yx-y-big2-big-frac2/2419536#2419536):
$$\sum_{x,y,z}\left(\dfrac{mx-ny}{x-y}\right)^2=\Big(\dfrac{my-nz}{y-z} - \dfrac{x(m-n)(z-y)}{(x-y)(z-x)}\Big)^2+m^2+n^2.$$ Taking $m = a$ and $n = -b$ will give us:
$$C = a^2+b^2 + \Delta ^2,\quad (2).$$
where $\Delta$ can be calculated from the linked answer.

Now let us recollect what we are trying to prove. we are trying to prove that the following is a non-negative quadratic:
$$L(c) - R(c) = (A - 2)c^2 + 2(B +a+b )c + (C-a^2 - b^2)\geq 0.$$
But this is equivalent to having a zero-discriminant and a non-negative leading coefficient, the latter of which is already checked $(1).$ From $(1),$ let's let $A - 2 = \Omega^2,$ then the discriminant condition is:
$$4(B-a-b)^2 = 4(A-2)(C-a^2-b^2)\iff B+a+b = \pm\Omega\Delta,\quad  (3).$$
But now this can be checked by hand since:
$$\begin{cases}
B+a+b = a\left(\dfrac{zx}{(x-y)^2}-1\right)+b\left(\dfrac{zy}{(x-y)^2}-1\right)\\
\Omega = \sum\dfrac{x}{y-z} \\
\Delta = a\left(\dfrac{y}{y-z} - \dfrac{x}{x-y}-\dfrac{x}{z-x}\right) + b\left(\dfrac{z}{y-z} - \dfrac{x}{x-y}-\dfrac{x}{z-x}\right)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: In $L(c)-R(c)$, should the 2nd term be $2(B+a+b)c$? (Already +1 some hours ago)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks! @River Li